# How re-calculate the window container/image width on resize?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method/function in React where i swipe to the left and right on click with a translate value from CSS. However, on render the screens are loaded, and will move to the left or right and translate value will be set correctly. But the problem is, when i try to resize the browser the calculation doesn't work.

I have tried creating a onClick={this.ResizeSlider} and from there run the function but doesn't work.

My code:

```
NextSlide = () => {
    const {
        currentIndex,
        data
    } = this.state;

    const slideWidth = this.slideWidth();
    // Exiting the method early if we are at the end of the images array.
    // We also want to reset currentIndex and translateValue, so we return
    // to the first image in the array.
    if(currentIndex === data.length - 1) {
        return this.setState({
        currentIndex: 0,
        translateValue: 0
        })
    }

    // This will not run if we met the if condition above
    this.setState(NextState => ({
        currentIndex: NextState.currentIndex + 1,
        translateValue: NextState.translateValue + -(slideWidth)
    }));
}

slideWidth = () => {
    const { slideClass } = this.state;
    return document.querySelector(slideClass).clientWidth
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an eventListener so you know when the screen size has changed.

Try something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.dimensionsChange();
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.dimensionsChange());
}
```

And you can access the width/height values in the dimensionsChange() method using:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

Don't forget to remove the event listener when your component unmounts:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", this.dimensionsChange());
}
```